# Display Magento Category Image

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Generally, the top menu will list out sub-category's name, I want to list out sub-category's image. Can anyone advise the php code.

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

It can be done by adding additional attribute into frontend categories attributes load list via config.xml:

```
<frontend>
    <category>
        <collection>
            <attributes>
                 <[attribute_code] />
            </attributes>
        </collection>
    </category>
</frontend>
```

Just replace `[attribute_code]` with image attribute code (maybe in your case it is `image`)

and then you will be able access category image via `$category->getImage()`, also it is possible that you will need to override `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` block for custom html formating of your menu.

When you complete this customization, don't forget to clean cache and rebuild flat categories index (if it is used).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. Do you know where is the php code that retrieve the cateogry and sub-category?

Comment: Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation it is here, but you need to create new module for this purpose, instead of modifying existing code.